# Random graphs simulation

Tags: simulation, random-graphs

Reading the article ["Emergence of scaling in random network, by Barabasi and Albert"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/condmat/9910332.pdf)

I faced a lot of results obtained by simulations of the A-B random graph model. I always wanted to do such simulations, but honestly I don't know how to start. There is a better programming language? There are packages? There is a special software to handle heavy data?

To put everything in one question: how they do that kind of simulation?